# Create automatically Sequence Diagram / List all methods from a c# application or Solution when executed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sequence-diagram

Lets imagine, i have a .dll / Solution in MS Visual Studio 2010 with 5 Classes, 20 Methods and 1 Breakpoint.

Now, i would like to start/debug the application and automatically create some kind of a sequence diagram from the breakpoint or just list all the methods which are beeing called.

I would kinda like to see the flow of the application!

edit: it should be free of charges. personal private use at home.

edit: any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems can do this.

Take a look at this [video](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/debuggingcs/debuggingcs.htm).